# Wrapping a Unix Executable in an iOS app

Tags: ios, c, unix, executable, porting

Is there a way to wrap a complied Unix executable that takes a parameter list as arguments into an iOS application?  I have been unsuccessful in finding documentation on how to do this for iOS. Though I have had success with macOS applications, I have found that there are differences which bar me from using the same technique.

Comment: Is this meant for the App Store? If so, you can't.

Comment: No it's not.  Is there still a way?

Comment: There is no tool that does this for you. What you need to do is write a very minimal iOS app in Xcode, compile your UNIX code to an archive library and edit the build properties of your app project to link against your archive library. The app code needs to (a) read your command line arguments from a text file that you include in the project and (b) call your UNIX code's entry point(s).